# Starting Service through Octopus powershell fails for timeout

Tags: .net, powershell, deployment, octopus-deploy, octopus

I want to deploy an application I built, and I am trying to start its through Octopus.
This executable is just a .net application that uses Topshelf to run as windows service. However it's not a Windows Service itself as just said.. it's just an app using Topshelf.
The way I run this executable through octopus is simply running the exe. Nothing more than a line of script calling this exe.
Unfortunately the error I get is this:

> The YourTestService service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
>   A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the YourTestService service to connect.

My service indeed, if started manually, takes a bit more than 1 minute.

By reading [here](https://help.octopus.com/t/start-service-timesout-after-20-seconds/2753) I see that this happens because I try to run the .exe through a powershell script, and the policy behind is that there is a default timeout of 20 seconds (according to what is written in that solution, but in my case this timeout is 30 seconds).

So I see 2 possible solutions:

1) increase the timeout policy somehow

2) run the exe in Octopus by not using my own made powershell script.

Can anyone help by any chance?

Comment: To call your .exe use bash/shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` and interval in all of my services. I'm trying to have 
`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.OnStart()` method very lightweight which just initialize base components. All my services are starting up withing few seconds.

If it's not possible in your case you can override default timeout in registry:

[Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839803/the-windows-trace-session-manager-service-does-not-start-and-event-id)